# Pandas .idxmin() Throwing ValueError with Groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with thousands of rows containing multiple entries for multiple people:

```
    Name        ID          Date
0   Person A    9999249491  2015-12-28
1   Person A    9999249491  2015-12-29
2   Person A    9999293341  2015-12-30
3   Person B    9999293341  2015-12-30
4   Person B    9999293341  2015-12-31
```

I want to find the *index* of the minimum `Date` for each person using `groupby()` and `idxmin()` but I am receiving a `ValueError` message when I execute the following:

```
df.groupby(['Name','ID'])['Date'].idxmin()
```

returns the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-153-ef18ad96a6d8> in <module>()
      3 t = df[['Name','ipg_id','Date']]
      4 
----> 5 t.groupby(['Name','ipg_id'])['Date'].idxmin()

C:\Users\nickb\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.pyc in idxmin(self, axis, out, skipna)

C:\Users\nickb\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.pyc in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    548                                                             *args, **kwargs)
    549                     except (AttributeError):
--> 550                         raise ValueError
    551 
    552         return wrapper

ValueError:
```

---

I can, however, execute the `min()` method without any problems:

```
df.groupby(['Name','ID'])['Date'].min()
```

returns:

```
Name        ID
Person A    9999249491    2015-12-28
Person B    9999293341    2015-12-30
```

I can't seem to figure out why I am receiving the `ValueError` message.  Any clues on getting `idxmin()` to work would be great.  Thank you.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with a similar problem and it doesn't look like you received an answer for this that worked.  Also, is this code for Python 3+ or 2?

Comment: I am pretty sure this was Python 2.7 (definitely a Python 2.x)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need set column `Date` to datetime before:

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
```

Comment: I thought the same thing as well but everything in the `Date` column is in `datetime` format:  `set([type(item) for item in df.Date])` produces: `{datetime.date}`

Comment: so df.Date.dtypes is `datetime` ?

Comment: `df.Date.dtypes` produces: `dtype('O')`.  `set([type(item) for item in df.Date])` produces: `{datetime.date}`

Comment: Yes, there is problem. You dont need object datetime, but dtype datetime. `df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)` doesnt work?

Comment: Nice, that worked.  I was originally converting string to date using with `[datetime.datetime.strptime(item, '%m/%d/%Y').date() for item in df.Date]`.  With `pd.to_datetime(df.Date)`, `df.Date.dtypes` now produces `dtype('<M8[ns]')`.  Should I avoid the list comprehension method in the future?